# ajax refresh script prevent session

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I created an ajax chat with PHP/MYSQL using a refresh :

```
var Alive = setInterval(function(){ /*ajax*/ }, 5000);
```

It works pretty well ! but im looking for a way to prevent 2 session in the same time (like if the user is connected on desktop then go on mobile without leave ) cause the script will continue and refresh the first session of the script. Any idea ? Maybe cancel/redirect the older session ? I dont know

Comment: Does your chat use authentication or is it anonymous?
If the same user is connected to the chat from different devices (or browsers), the session will be different so you have no way to know that it's the same user.

Comment: its use authentification

Answer (score 1):

As your chat uses authentication, you can use an access token.

Every time the user logs in, create a new token (based on a hash of the user's id and the current timestamp for example) and store it into the database in your user table and in the session. ( `$_SESSION['accessToken'] = $token` )
Set the column to null when the user disconnects manually.

Now, everytime the server receives a request, check the token. If the session one matches the database one, it's ok, else the user logged in from somewhere else or closed his browser in the meantime. In that case, call your disconnect function.

To be really sure that the user stays the same, generate a new token at every request too.

You can use something similar to this to check if the tokens match:

```
    $db = getDB();
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=:email AND access_token=:accessToken;');
    $query->execute([
            "email"         => $_SESSION["email"], /* Assuming you store the user's info into the session when he logs in */
            "accessToken"   => $_SESSION["accessToken"]
    ]);

    if($query->rowCount()) {
        //The user didn't change device/browser
        $query->closeCursor();
        $_SESSION["accessToken"] = generateAccessToken($_SESSION["email"]);
        //Don't forget to update the token in the database too
    } else {
        //The user changed device/browser without disconnecting manually
        $query->closeCursor();
        disconnectUser(); //Destroys the session and sets the access token to null
    }
```

Now that the user is disconnected, you can respond with a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code. Stop your script from looping when receiving a 403 status.